# Is the RSS feed for the Stack Overblog broken?

Tags: support, bug, blog, feed

https://stackoverflow.blog/feed is returning a 400 error. Is this intentional? Is the RSS feed being removed or is this just a bug?

Comment: Related: *[How can I subscribe to the podcast?](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/304073/how-can-i-subscribe-to-the-podcast/304075#304075)*